# Is copying an NSMutableArray thread-safe?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-foundation

Let's say I have a mutable array containing some objects in the variable `array`.

Let's say from thread `A` I do:

```
NSArray *arrayCopy = [array copy];
```

and from thread `B`:

```
[array addObject:NSNull.null];
```

Is it safe? Specifically, can this code crash because of a potential modification of `array` while it is being copied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  [Mutating an `NSMutableArray` is not a thread safe operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html).

Comment: @Frizlab It can lead to unexpected results, which *may* include crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Apple says that NSMutableArray is not thread-safe. However if you add objects in one thread and copy in other, it won't crash. If you add object from different threads, it would crash.

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

var array = NSMutableArray()
var queues = [NSOperationQueue]()

let syncQueue = NSOperationQueue()
syncQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

for i in 0..<100 {
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    queues.append(queue)

    queue.addOperationWithBlock({
        for j in 0..<100000 {
            if j == 0 {
                sleep(1)
            } else {
                usleep(j < 5 ? 100 : rand() % 10 == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            }

            if i % 2 == 0 {
                syncQueue.addOperationWithBlock({
                    array.addObject(NSNumber(int: rand()))
                })
            } else {
                var copy = array.copy()
            }
        }
    })
}

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

However, I didn't find documentation, where it will be described (that copy function is thread safe on NSMutableArray). If someone provides a link, I'll appreciate.